# WCF (Rest) service errors when JSON object has a long string

Tags: c#, wcf, json

I have a WCF service implemented using the WebServiceHostFactory (REST).

I'm calling a service end point as a POST sending a json object that has a string property.

This works up to a point but it seems that if the length of that string gets too long (not sure exactly how long (8000 chars works but 9000 does not ... I did not try but 'breaking point' might be 8192).

I attempt to check the StatusCode in the call back which works fine for smaller strings but when the sting is 'too long' the code below errors with:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

Callback code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
```

I'm trying to figure out where the problem is, since the service exists and I only get this when the string is too long.

Is it the json object size?  Is it my service definition?  Is this something in WCF?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is problem with [MaxStringContentLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionaryreaderquotas.maxstringcontentlength.aspx) property from reader quotas. Its default value is indeed 8192. You can change the value in binding configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="LargeString">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="16000" />
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Reference this binding configuration in your endpoint configuration:

```
  <endpoint address="..." contract="..." binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeString" />
```

In case of WCF 4.0 you can omit name in binding definition and it should be used as default configuration for all webHttp endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a reasons without knowing it. Maybe you exceed the maximum message length? This can be set in your App.Config file.

If you have a vast amount of data to transfer you could either use streaming or build your own API just like cursors work in SQL.